# Animated PowerPoint Slides in c#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have a small c# Software that controls a PowerPoint SlideShow (Commands are received from extern over a persistent HTTP Connection). Currently I support forward, next and gotoSlide_x. Before the SlideShow starts, my Software iterates over all the Slides and sends Data like NumberOfSlides, Titles and Notes to my controling Software. If there is a Slide which requires multiple Next commands, like slides where single items show up after a User presses Next, my Tool runs in problems, because my controling component does not know about these Slides.

Perhaps someone could point out the right API for those kind of Slides. I would like to know for Slide_i, how often do I have to press next in order to reach Slide_i+1.

Answer (score 0):

There is a TimeLine in Slide. From TimeLine I can find the Effects of a Slide. They have to be checked against the TriggerType. My relevant code looks like this (s is a Slide):

```
int numOfAnimations = 0;
foreach (Effect e in s.TimeLine.MainSequence)
{
    if (e.Timing.TriggerType == MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick)
    {
        numOfAnimations++;
    }
}
```

Could it be that there is hardly any documentation about that kind of stuff, or did I search wrong?